# SQL Server: Get location of transaction log from MDF file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore

Our SQL Server 2012 Express server crashed and lost some data. We managed to rescue the main MDF, but can't find the LDF. Is there a way to get this information from the database MDF file or msdb, or temp mdfs that were found?

Comment: Where is that located? I was only able to attach the temp database, but came up empty.

Comment: Sorry, by main db I meant my application's database. That is 26 GB. How do you open to view it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: try to query sys.master_files

Comment: @BobKlimes - sounds like they only have tempdb and msdb files

Comment: Do you have an old backup of that database? runing a `RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'YourBackupPath\YourBackupFile.bak';` would list the path of the database files when the backup was taken.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is stored in a couple or locations in the MDF.

1. the base table `sysprufiles` - I've checked a few databases installed locally and found it on page 155 and page 153 of the ones I've checked. I imagine this will always be fairly early in the file but it doesn't appear to have a fixed location.
2. `sysfiles1` - which is reliably on page 32 for every database I have checked so far.

The initial version of this answer used a hex editor to read it from the MDF.

[Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman) points out there is an undocumented DBCC command that is  massively simpler.

```
DBCC CHECKPRIMARYFILE ( N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf',1);
```

Returns a result like

```
+--------+---------+-------+---------+--------+---------+------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| fileid | groupid | size  | maxsize | growth | status  | perf |          name           |                                           filename                                           |
+--------+---------+-------+---------+--------+---------+------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 |       1 | 26240 |      -1 |   2048 |       2 |    0 | AdventureWorks2012_Data | C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf |
|      2 |       0 |   128 |      -1 |     10 | 1048642 |    0 | AdventureWorks2012_Log  | C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQL2012\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_log.ldf  |
+--------+---------+-------+---------+--------+---------+------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I was curious as to how that approach worked so looked at the activity in process monitor.

[image]

This ends up reading the file header (page 0), database boot page (page 9) and page 32 of the file.

I didn't see page 32 mentioned on either of the preceding pages so I think that page is hardcoded to contain the information rather than being looked up from them.

Comment: Tried with different offsets, but couldn't find it...

Comment: This is quite a crucial table to the database - it can't exist without it and needs to be there at initial creation so it is very likely to be early in the file. Maybe just start at offset 0 and load the first 1,000 pages (8,192,000 bytes and use the "find" function to look for the Unicode string `.ldf`)

Comment: I just did the same and found it much earlier in the file too at offset 263,298 - I'll need to re-attach the DB to see what that page is

Comment: Ah that is `sysfiles1`. Which was page 32 in that MDF

Comment: @Rick - Can you try offset `262144` in case `sysfiles1` happens to be more reliably on page 32 than `sysprufiles` is with its location?

Comment: Found it on that one. Thanks!

Comment: Another option is the undocumented DBCC command, like `DBCC CHECKPRIMARYFILE ( N'D:\SqlFiles\YourDatabase.mdf',1);`

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks, that looks considerably easier!